# Passing current tab url to server in angular resources fetch

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send the current tab url to the resource service { in param } .
but the global tablUrl is not having any value at 
    var url = "http://[localhost]/getProfile?domain="+tabUrl

but getting logged corrent at :

```
console.log(tabUrl);
```

this is my code :

```
var tabUrl;
angular.module('jsonService', ['ngResource'])
.factory('JsonService', function($resource) {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        tabUrl = tab.url;
        console.log(tabUrl);
    });
    var url = "http://[localhost]/getProfile?domain="+tabUrl
  return $resource(url,{}, {
    list : {
      method : 'GET',
     cache : true
    }
 });
});
```

template binding :

```
  <body ng-controller="extensionCtrl">
```

this is controller :

```
app.controller('extensionCtrl', function($scope , JsonService) {
 JsonService.get(function(data){
   $scope.data = data;
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:
Please, don't use the deprecated **chrome.tabs.getSelected**. Use **[chrome.tabs.query](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query)** instead.

Second:
`chrome.tabs.getSelected`/`chrome.tabs.query` are **asynchronous**. This means that execution continues while they do some work in the background and the specified callback is called when they are done.
So, in a case like this:

```
line 1: chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, funkyCallback);
line 2: var url = ...
line 3: return $resource(...);
```

...a possible (and very probable) order of execution is:

```
1. chrome.tabs.getSelected (starts retrieving the active tab in the background)
2. line 2 gets executed (at this time 'tabURL' is not set yet)
3. line 3 gets executed (returning something)
4. Once the the active tab is retrieved, 'funkyCallback' is called
   (setting 'tabURL' after it is too late).
```

When using asynchronous APIs (such as most of the **chrome.*** APIs), you have to change the whole logic of your scripts to be in line with the asynchronous nature of the API calls.

E.g., you could achieve the same result like this:

**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="jsonService">
    ...
    <body ng-controller="extensionCtrl">
        <p>{{jsonData}}</p>
        ...
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module("jsonService", ["ngResource"]);

app.factory("JsonFactory", function($resource) {
    var url = "http://localhost/getProfile?domain=:tabUrl";
    var retObj = $resource(url, {}, {
        list: {
            method: "GET",
            cache: true
        }
    });
    return retObj;
});

app.controller("extensionCtrl", function($q, $rootScope, JsonFactory) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function(tabs) {
        JsonFactory.list({ tabUrl: tabs[0].url }, function(data) {
            // On success...
            $rootScope.jsonData = data;
        }, function(data) {
            // On error...
            $rootScope.jsonData = "Error using JsonFactory.list(...) !";
        });
    });
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/eLj5J/)** that does something similarly asynchronous

Comment: var url = "http://localhost/test.php?domain=:tabUrl";  how to test this line .. i checked in db tabUrl are going blank .

Comment: $scope.url = tab.url; doing this and checking by {{url}} template shows nothing.

Comment: UPDATED the answer (again) ! There was an error with the parameters of the **chrome.tabs.query** callback: It returns an array of Tab objects, so `tab.url` should actually be `tabs[0].url`.